# Como comparar 2 arrays para encontrar qual valor está faltando em uma delas, usando PHP

Tags: php, array

Tenho 2 arrays e preciso fazer uma comparação entre elas, para encontrar quais valores estão faltando na 2ª array (`$arrayxml`), por exemplo:

```
$arraybd=array('1','2','3','4');
$arrayxml=array('1','2');
```

Nesse caso está faltando os valores `'3'` e `'4'` na `$arrayxml`, então pegaria esses valores `'3'` e `'4'` para poder executar a tarefa que preciso (vou removê-la do banco de dados).

O ideal seria gerar uma string, ou  mesmo uma array com os valores que estão faltando, no caso acima, ficaria:

```
$valoresdiferentes=('3','4')
```

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função [`array_diff_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff-assoc.php), ela faz exatamente o que você quer.

```
$arraybd=array('1','2','3','4');
$arrayxml=array('1','2');
$diferencas = array_diff_assoc($arraybd, $arrayxml);
print_r($diferencas);
```

Comment: show, qual a diferença do array_diff_assoc e array_diff?

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo a array_diff_assoc também inclui as chaves na comparação, caso queria somente os values use o array_diff mesmo, exemplo, se você tem um array da seguinte forma $array("a" => "valor1", "b" => "valor2"); e outro array $array2("valor1", "b" => "valor2"); Ele vai considerar o "valor1" do array2 como diferente pois não tem a chave "a"

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar a função `array_diff()`.

```
$arraybd=array('1','2','3','4');
$arrayxml=array('1','2');

$result = array_diff($arrayxml, $arraybd);

print_r($diferencas);

//irá printar 3 e 4
```

Segundo a [documentação do php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff.php), deve-se passar primeiro o array a ser comparado, e depois o array para comparar. O resultado será sempre todas entradas do array 1 que não estou nos outros arrays.